# jenkins does not detect the last changes Commited to SVN

Tags: svn, jenkins

i am new to jenkins ,when i commit my code to SVN , jenkins should update the code in its work space to the latest committed code when build but it does not.  when i add new file it update the code successfuly

can any one help me please

My configurations :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you know it did not trigger on commit? Did you wait the 5 minutes (that's your configured polling interval)

Review the Subversion Polling Log (link on the left side of the job page), and paste it here after the 5 minute mark.

**Polling can also fail if you have big time difference between your Jenkins server and SVN server (most common mistake one being setup with correct timezone, and another being left as GMT)**

Comment: It also makes sense to check HTTPD's log to see whether Jenkins actually contacts the server.